# Ubuntu 15.10 + Dell XPS 13 2015 + Enlarging \boot partition

Tags: boot, partitioning, dell, 15.10, gparted

I am attempting to increase the partition size of '/boot' (recent update put strain on the current ~250 MB partition) but running into problems as GParted (when run from a LiveCD) will not recognize my HDD.

This is odd considering that 'fdisk -l' does.  I have tried unmounting and remounting the HDD, to no avail.  Also, I have played around with the SATA setup in boot options (RAID and AHCI), but this does not appear to help either (AHCI is my default setting for SATA).

I am not sure if the fact that if the file system of this drive (ext3/ext4) is part of the problem or what, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried the drop-down menu on the right side of the toolbar which lets you choose your device?

Comment: 250MB should however be more than sufficient for /boot? how did you manage to fill it?

Comment: @spacelander, yeah I tried this, and I can see other devices such as another USB when I plug it in.  I have found that 300MB-500MB is now being considered the recommended /boot partition size for future versions of linux. I made sure to remove all previous linux-images as well before going through this hassle and will try and strip it down even further, but instead of dealing with this problem later I wanted to try and solve it now.

Comment: Does fdisk or gdisk complain about corrupted partition table?

Comment: fdisk output is: (http://textuploader.com/5zfri)  and gdisk output is: (http://textuploader.com/5zfrw). Both of which seem sensible, though I am admittedly not that familiar with output int terms of gdisk to say that, it may be the source of the problem.

Comment: You need to download the newest gparted since you have NVMe drives. gparted should be at least version 0.24.0-1 to recognize NVMe devices. With standard desktop installs better not to have separate /boot partition. Use separate /home or data partition. But you still need to manually houseclean old kernels whether you have separate /boot partition or just boot inside / (root).

Comment: Yes, you need to update, just as @oldfred said

Comment: @oldfred: Thanks for the tip. I am in the process of doing this now, but I think that version 0.19.0 (what most people probably have) actually will see NVMe drives, if there are no other drives present other than NVMe's.  I say this because I tested it prior to installing version 0.25.0 and this was the case.  That said, I have another possible concern in that my partition /dev/nvme0n1p3 is encrpyted, and I may not be able to resize it (and expand) the /boot partition (that is the impression I am getting at least looking at GParted within my Ubuntu 15.10 installation.

Comment: If you did full drive encryption with LVM, then you need LVM tools for the logical partition(s). And it is extremely complicated to expand /boot. You have to do many steps to shrink LVM, resize it, shrink physical partition and move it. All is very risky. Better to just regularly houseclean kernels.

Comment: Fred, you are 100% correct about that. I just looked into it (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeEncryptedPartitions) and it is quite involved to say the least. My question is having house cleaned the kernels, as I did as a first step before even attempting this, is there anything else to do? I do believe 250 MB should be enough in boot, as did _spacelander_, which makes me wonder why the latest Security updates (including the keyring exploit patch) though only 67 MB in size to dl, requiring "a total of 183 M free space on disk '/boot'.  That is the real question here tbh. Thanks.

Comment: To give you an idea of what I have going on in /boot see (http://textuploader.com/5zf2f) where, at least to the best of my knowledge I have a single linux kernel installed (4.2.0-23), though admittedly it is somewhat large.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This problem started with the need to increase my /boot partition to make way for a rather large Ubuntu security update (4.2.0-25, meant to address the key ring exploit) which called for 183 MB free space.

This was inordinately large, as far as software updates go, especially for users that have /boot separately partitioned (where 250 MB is historically regarded as more than enough space).  Beyond **removing old kernel images (as is the first step when it comes to cleaning /boot out)** I had to also **remove a .old-dkms-backup file (which a first made sure to backup)**, which thankfully freed up enough space.  However, the fact that these newer kernel images (for 4.2. at least) are nearly twice the size (35 MB compared to 20 MB) of their 3.13 counterparts means that for **those installing newer Linux kernels (4.2 and onward) may want to set aside ~ 500 MB for their /boot partitions to avoid this problem.**